# Casting issue when trying to use pointers to member functions

Tags: c++, casting, struct, static-methods, pointer-to-member

For several reasons, I must use a struct defined in an extern C lib. I have simplified my code in order to make it readable.

#### Struct defined in C Lib

```cpp
extern "C" {
    typedef struct {
        double (*_function)(double x);
    } FuncR;
}
```

#### Cpp file containing class A

```cpp
Class A {
public:
    A();
    void foo(double x); // Cannot be static since it uses m
    void bar();
private:
    double m; // non-static member by nature
};

void A::bar() {
    FuncR f;
    f._function = &A::foo;
};
```

The call `f._function = &A::foo;` generates the following error :

`error C2440 : '=' : cannot convert from 'double (__thiscall A::*)(double)' to 'double(__cdecl*)(double)'`

I have been searching for answers and apparently `foo`must be declared static. In my case it is not possible since it has to use non-static members...

Is there any trick to solve my problem ?

Comment: Ok, so the struct defined in the extern C lib can't be changed, and you gotta use it, I dunno why.  Who uses the funcptr in the struct to actually make the function call, your new C++ code or something in the extern C lib?

Comment: If you read my original answer and dismissed it as 'wrong', please read the additions I made to it which make it right!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the FuncR struct really need to be defined/used in C code?  Can you use C++-style member function pointers?

How about this?...

```
class A;

struct classA_MemberFuncR {
    double(A::*_function)(double);
};

class A {
public:
    A() : m(1.234) {};
    double foo(double x) {
        std::cout << "In foo(" << x << "): this="
                << (void*)this << ", m=" << m << '\n';
        return m+x;
    }
    void bar();
private:
    double m; // non-static member by nature
};

void A::bar() {
    classA_MemberFuncR fm;
    fm._function = &A::foo;
    double result = (this->*fm._function)(4.321);
    std::cout << "Result is: " << result << std::endl;
};
```

[Comment added at this point:] Dang.  Re-read OP's original post.  (Supposedly we're stuck with the C struct's non-member function pointer.)

Hmm.  On GCC I tried a whole lot of casting combinations and it never let me cast M::foo's address to much of anything else, so I wrote a runtime cast function template to force it to allow me to cast anything at all to any other type I want without complaining (Everyone: Please hold off on the screams of "that's not portable!" Sure it's portable... It's just how you use it that may or may not be portable!):

```
/*---- In a header file somewhere... ----*/
#include <stdarg.h>
template <typename ToTy, typename FromTy>
ToTy forceCast_helper(int dummy, ...);

template <typename ToTy, typename FromTy>
inline ToTy forceCast(FromTy obj) {
    // ...has nothing to do with Star Wars!
    return forceCast_helper<ToTy,FromTy>(1, obj);
}

/*---- In a source file somewhere... ----*/
template <typename ToTy, typename FromTy>
ToTy forceCast_helper(int dummy, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, dummy);
    ToTy ret = va_arg(args, ToTy);
    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
```

Which allowed me to compile the following code without error:

```
typedef double(*doubleFuncDouble_t)(double);
typedef double(A::*doubleClassAMemberfuncDouble_t)(double);

f._function = forceCast<doubleFuncDouble_t>(&A::foo);

// and then call this->foo(4.321) with it from within A::bar() as follows...

(this->*(forceCast<doubleClassAMemberfuncDouble_t>(f._function)))(4.321);
```

Unfortunately when it ran, it segfaulted.  Further investigation shows that, at least on GCC for 32-bit Linux for x86, sizeof(a member function pointer) is 8, while sizeof(a nonmember function pointer) is 4.  When I changed the type of FuncR::_function to uint64_t, amazingly, the call succeeded.  (I was surprised as well.)

So it seems regardless of any casting magic you might find that compiles without error, there's really no way at all you'd ever be able to squeeze a member function pointer into a nonmember function pointer, at least on GCC for 32-bit x86.  And even if you could, that doesn't encapsulate the 'this' pointer, as 'unwind' mentioned in his post.

---

I think there's still hope, though.

unwind's post suggests a trampoline function but concedes that it would require separately passing the 'this' pointer & managing that in the C code as a void*.  I'm assuming your C library is not modifiable?  If so, you should still be able to do a trampoline without being able to pass a 'this' pointer through it, assuming you have a limited number of such function pointers you'll need to be specifying:

You could create an array of class A object pointers, sized to however many of these FuncR function pointer objects you'll be using:

```
A* arrayThatHoldsAObjPointers[8]; // assuming you only need 8 such FuncR func ptr objects
```

Then create that many physical static nonmember functions (each conveniently named with a suffix number corresponding with its associated array index), and in the body of each, make them call A::foo() via its associated 'A' object in the arrayThatHoldsAObjPointers:

```
double trampoline_0(double d) { return arrayThatHoldsAObjPointers[0]->foo(d); }
double trampoline_1(double d) { return arrayThatHoldsAObjPointers[1]->foo(d); }
...and so on...
```

Then when you need to set a FuncR object for use by your C library, give it the address of one of the trampolines, and at the same time, store the pointer to that A object in the associated arrayThatHoldsAObjPointers[] element.  To make the code that sets these easier to use, you could also create an array of function pointers to the trampolines.

Comment: Doing this seems to make class A undefined since the array needs definition of A which needs the array...

Comment: @vanna - You don't need the definition of A in order to define an array of pointers to A objects.  Just forward-declare 'A' as a class but don't define it (see the first line of my answer's first code block), and the definition of the array will succeed.  But of course, to call `arrayThatHoldsAObjPointers[0]->foo(d);` you must have defined A by that point.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think there's a trick to "fix" this.

The method call needs a `this` pointer, which the function pointer can't handle.

Often you can define a static "trampoline" function to get you into a method, but that requires that the outer layers (the C code, in this case) supports passing around e.g. a  `void *` where you can store the `this` pointer.